# QT. Add new layout to QLayout

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtablewidget, qlayout

I create interface dynamically when Application is run.

1) I have QTabWidget with 4 predefined tabs. But i must show only 1 or 2 tabs, in case of user shoice. On StackOverflow i learned, that i must keep all tabs in collection to add and destroit it.

I have QHash: `twInputMethodsTabs = new QHash< int, QPair<QWidget*, QString> >();`

First argument = index; Second = Tab Widget; Third = Tab Widget Caption Text;

2) I fill the collection like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ui->twInputMethods->children().length(); i++)
    {
        twInputMethodsTabs->insert(i, QPair<QWidget*, QString>(ui->twInputMethods->widget(i), ui->twInputMethods->tabText(i)));
    }
```

3) I add new widget in the tab like this:

`twInputMethodsTabs->value(1).first->layout()->addWidget(cmbbCommands);`

4) How can i add new layout to this widget? I want to do like this:

```
QHBoxLayout *hblParams  =new QHBoxLayout();
twInputMethodsTabs->value(1).first->layout()->addLayout(hblParams);
```

But it does not work, because `layout()` returns `QLayout` which havent `addLayout()` function. How i can do this?

Or how can i should change architecture of code to do this?

Comment: Layouts can be applied on QWidgets only. What you have to do is to insert a widget and apply the new layout to the widget.

Comment: Tab widgets can contain the layout to align all items in it. In example above i add widget on this layout - it works fine. Now, i want to add couple of widgets, aligned both one by one. I think something like this:`TabWidget (has Layout(has widget, Layout(has widget, widget)))`. More clearly?

Comment: @gek0n What makes you think "Tab widgets can contain the layout to align all items in it."? There is no way to apply a layout to a tab (because it's not a `QWidget`). What you *can* do is create a container `QWidget` to hold your layout and associated widgets. Then add this container to the tab.

Comment: @mfitzp what do you mean ? a tab is actually a QWidget : `QTabWidget::addTab(QWidget *page, const QString &label)`

Comment: @gek0n is the content of your tabs dynamically changing during execution ? If not just create everything once at beginning and don't play with the widgets you store in the hash. Otherwise if you are sure of what layout you previously put in your widgets you can cast `twInputMethodsTabs->value(1).first->layout()`to the actual layout and use addLayout.

Comment: @ymoreau it was the use of the phrase 'tab widget' that made it sound as though the tab was a special *kind* of widget. Rather than each tab being formed from a supplied widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this following code you get a widget (`.first`) and then select that widget's layout `->layout()` and then add a Widget to that layout `->addWidget()`.

```
twInputMethodsTabs->value(1).first->layout()->addWidget(cmbbCommands);
```

In the following code you get a widget (`.first`) and then select that widget's layout `->layout()` and try to set the layout on the layout.

```
twInputMethodsTabs->value(1).first->layout()->addLayout(hblParams);
```

#### Replacing the QLayout

To set the layout on the parent widget, you need to drop the `->layout()`:

```
twInputMethodsTabs->value(1).first->addLayout(hblParams);
```

Note that since you are now adding an empty layout to the widget, any widgets current in the previous layout will be lost, so you may need to re-add the widgets to the layout.

#### Adding new QLayout inside existing QLayout

If you want to add a layout into the existing layout, you cannot do this directly. `QLayout` can only accept `QWidget` via `.addWidget()`. However, you can apply a layout to an empty `QWidget()` and then add *that* to the layout. For example:

```
QWidget *w = new QWidget();
w.addLayout(hblParams);
twInputMethodsTabs->value(1).first->layout()->addWidget(w);
```

An alternative is to set the layout on the `QWidget` to a layout that does support `.addLayout()` such as `QHBoxLayout` or `QVBoxLayout`. For example:

```
QVBoxLayout *l = new QVBoxLayout();
cmbbCommands.setLayout(l);  // Now has a layout that supports .addLayout
twInputMethodsTabs->value(1).first->layout()->addWidget(cmbbCommands);
```

Now the following should work because `->layout()` returns a `QVBoxLayout`:

```
QHBoxLayout *hblParams  =new QHBoxLayout();
twInputMethodsTabs->value(1).first->layout()->addLayout(hblParams);
```

Comment: No No No. It's not what i want. I do not want replace old layout with new layout. I want to add new layout INSIDE old layout. Just like a widget. I need do it to group other widgets in layout on tab widget.

Comment: @gekon Then you need to state that in your question. For what it's worth "No No No." is a rude way to speak to someone who is trying to help you.

Comment: It's just bad emotion, coz i can't speak in english clearly. Ok. When i chose VerticalLayout for MainWindow. The i add into MainWindow HorizontalLayout and 3 buttons into it. Then i add into MainWindow another HorizontalLayout and 3 InputText into it. And it's work fine.

But i don't know how to do same thing in tabwidget

Comment: Ok. I think it's only one way to do this - like your describe

Comment: @gek0n there may be another way (see the update). If you set the layout to `QVBoxLayout()` (or any other layout type that supports `.addLayout()` then the `->layout()` call will return this type, and your original code should work.

Answer (score 1):

I Hope, I get what you want to do:

```
twInputMethodsTabs->value(1).first->layout()->addWidget(cmbbCommands);

QHBoxLayout *hblParams  =new QHBoxLayout();
QWidget *w = new QWidget(twInputMethodsTabs->value(1).first);
twInputMethodsTabs->value(1).first->layout()->addWidget(w);

w->addLayout(hblParams);
```

I just wrote the code here, so it is untested. However it should give you an idea what I tried to explain in my comment.

Comment: I think it's bad way. There is good way somewhere. Why i can add as many layouts as i want to any widget in `QT Designer`, but can't do same trick programmatically?

Comment: In designer the layout widget is just a QWidget with a layout already applied. And this is exactly the way you would do that programmatically, What makes you think, that this is a bad way? Maybe you can explain, what you mean by that.

Comment: No, i can't explain. I just doesn't know how it do in designer, so i couldn't say is that way bad or good. So i think "maybe there is more good way". But as you say - it's the only one trueway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cutted from "working" application:

```
  WidgetA::WidgetA(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
  {
      QVBoxLayout *pLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
      buildWidget(pLayout);
      this->setLayout(pLayout);
  }

void WidgetA::buildWidget(QVBoxLayout *layout){
  for(int i=0; i<4; ++i){
       this->buildSegments(layout);
  }
}

void WidgetA::buildSegments(QVBoxLayout *layout){
    QHBoxLayout *pHbl = new QHBoxLayout();
    QLabel *pSegmentSize = new QLabel(this);
    pSegmentSize->setText(tr("Segment Size(1,N)"));
    QSpinBox *pSegments = new QSpinBox(this);
    pHbl->addWidget(pSegmentSize);
    pHbl->addWidget(pSegments);
    layout->addItem(pHbl);
}
```

Read this one: [Widgets Tutorial - Nested Layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-widgets-nestedlayouts-example.html)